# show file name instead of full path in text box

Tags: c#

How to display filename instead of full path when selecting file through OpenFileDialog in C# on visual studio 2010?

I tried of FileName, but it returns full path of file.

Comment: you want OFD to hide the path or you dont want to be bothered with the path in the result?

Answer (score 3):

Use [Path.GetFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

```
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileDialog.FileName);
```

If you want to exclude the extension you can use [Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

[`OpenFileDialog.SafeFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.safefilename.aspx) Gets the file name and extension for the file selected in the dialog box. The file name does not include the path.